# Config server to display error "Call to undefined method stdClass::"

Tags: php, apache

How can i display PHP error

> "Call to undefined method stdClass::"?

How have i to configure PHP5 or apache2?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`method_exists()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.method-exists.php) method to get that a function is present or not.

```
method_exists('Directory','read');
                ^^^         ^^^
               class_name   method_name
```

And use the below code

```
ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL);
```

at the top of your php code to get the all errors.

Comment: I tried it too but nothing happens more. The php.ini is configured as development mode, log error error report etc are On.

Comment: @user2090870 you can also check by set the display_errors on. like this: `ini_set('display_errors',"on");` try this also.

Answer (score 0):

set error_reporting = on in your PHP.ini file

or error_reporing(E_ALL); in your page

https://www.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.error-reporting

Comment: Yes, i tried it but nothing happens. I could not get same bug from my web hosting :( That sucks!